# Anchor tag relative path issue

Tags: php, html

I have a PHP/Apache2 shopping website, in that.ehtml extension also parse as php file. one of my category url `shirts` is

```
http://mydevserver:8083/bllaa.allshop/shop.ehtml/shirts.html
```

pagination links for `shirts` are relative

```
<div class="page-numbers">
    <span data-i18n="shop.front.Pages">Pages:</span>
    <span>1</span>
    <a class="focus" href="?page=2">2</a>
</div>
```

I expected the url will be

```
http://mydevserver:8083/bllaa.allshop/shop.ehtml/shirts.html?page=2
```

But the pagination link goes to

```
http://mydevserver:8083/bllaa.allshop/shop.ehtml?page=2
```

There is no JavaScript for that, why this strange behavior ?

Comment: *"There is no JavaScript for that, why this strange behavior ?"* - so why the js tag?

Comment: @Fred-ii- I have removed tag

Comment: Is apache rewriting, or redirecting the URL (does the URL change from `http://mydevserver:8083/bllaa.allshop/shop.ehtml/shirts.html` to `http://mydevserver:8083/bllaa.allshop/shop.ehtml` after you navigate to it)?

Comment: @TomPietrosanti I have right clicked link, and copied link location . the copied link itself `http://mydevserver:8083/bllaa.allshop/shop.ehtml?page=2`

Comment: Sorry, I meant in the address bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ohh finally I found issue. The site generated `<base>` tag in head.

```
<base href="/bllaa.allshop/shop.ehtml "/>
```

This causes strange behavior in relative path of anchor link.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to do

```
<a class="focus" href="shirts.html?page=2">2</a>
```

the anchor tags goes to the root if you dont provide a html page.
now it goes to the root, that is http://mydevserver:8083/bllaa.allshop/shop.ehtml?page=2

but when you provide shirts.html it goes to http://mydevserver:8083/bllaa.allshop/shop.ehtml/shirts.html?page=2